# Slack webhook not sending personal message

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I am trying to send personal message to particular user using webhook. I created webhook so i am getting personal message. But I am not able to send personal message to others personal chat. I don't want to use bot.

```
slack.setWebhook("Webhook");
slack.webhook({
    channel: "D01KMUZ4E4S",
    username: "webhookbot",
    text: "This is posted to #general and comes from a bot named webhookbot."
  }, function(err, response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: It may not be wise to post the webhook URL publicly. Anybody can use it, and when they do it will send a message to whatever channel or user it is linked to in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Slack Webhook URLs are tied to a particular channel, individual message, or group message. You need to create a new webhook in your workspace for each user you would like to send messages to.

Comment: But before it worked. Now i created new webhook and it is not working

Comment: @Dinesh In what way is your new URL not working?

Comment: Before I gave other channel ID and it posted messages to their DM. But now it is saying channel not found error